# Bidirectional references in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, doctrine-odm, bidirectional-relation

PHP Doctrine has support for [bi-directional references](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/bidirectional-references.html). I wonder if MongoEngine has something similar to this, so that when, for example, I add a post of a user, I don't need to manually keep both sides synced.

I could also only store the reference on the `many` side of a `one-to-many` relationship, and
use something like `Post(user=user_a)` to get user_a's all posts. But I would like to know the trade-offs of the two approaches. Also, how about many-to-many relationships?

Much appreciated!

Comment: You do realize that MongoDB is not a transactional database? I.e. it's impossible to guarantee such consistency on the database level (unless you implement your own transactions).

Comment: Thanks @freakish! Yeah so I wonder how people usually achieve this bi-directional references in MongoEngine, like manually updating on both sides? Or it's simply not a common use case? I feel its convenience tho. Thanks again!